# What login/password do I need to install a wordpress theme?

Tags: themes

I clicked to download a wordpress theme, and it asked me for user name and password. But I gave it my ftp password and it said invalid. Then I gave it my Wordpress credentials and it said invalid.

So which credentials does it need?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: 'download' from where? what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So which credentials does it need?

If you are able to see the download form, then presumably your WordPress user credentials are OK. So, you need (s)FTP credentials. Either you got the username/password wrong or there is something site specific getting in the way, maybe at the server level.

Comment: I keep trying my typical FTP and SFTP login, but it doesn't work :(